# A Common Lisp reference for finding and learning about built-in functions

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am learning Common Lisp, and I cannot for the life of me find a reference (other than textbooks) for quickly looking up what functions do, or whether a function exists.  For example, if I want to lookup what `mapcar` does, or find out if Lisp has a built-in `factorial` function, I would like to be able to refer to some place where I can find this out.  Where should I be looking?

I am thinking something like what `cplusplus.com`, or `cppreference.com` provide.

Comment: Links to the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm) and other resources can be found on the [common-lisp tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/common-lisp/info).

Comment: @adabsurdum what I was looking for, thanks!  I you post answer I will resolve it.

Comment: The HyperSpec could be a little bit intimidating at the beginning, I would suggest to use it in the addition to https://jtra.cz/stuff/lisp/sclr/index.html which is a (very much) simplified reference. It helped me a lot when I started digging in Common Lisp.

Comment: I have a very strong feeling that OP had been looking for something like that @Robert .. [sclr](https://jtra.cz/stuff/lisp/sclr/index.html)!!!

Comment: In addition to the other references, a very practical booklet of very few pages that can be printed and folded is here: http://clqr.boundp.org/

Comment: You could also have a look to the Cookbook: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/ look at its `data structures` or `strings` or `files` pages: they show the existing functions (kinda a reference), and give more recipes.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Common Lisp Quick Reference](http://clqr.boundp.org/)

Common Lisp Quick Reference is a free booklet with short descriptions of the thousand or so symbols defined in the ANSI standard. It comes with a comprehensive index.

This rather humble effort is by no means meant to rival the [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm) or any of the great introductory web resources and books. Its purpose is to give those who like a piece of dead tree in their hands a quick overview on things they know already, or some clue on what to look up elsewhere.

It is written in LaTeX and formatted for printing on both A4 and letter paper. After folding the sheets lengthwise, they can easily be turned into a handy booklet.

Answer (score 0):

You would have came across `HyperSpec` if you just would have googled for `Common Lisp <your function>`. So I use google. And sometimes `HyperSpec` is the hit. Or sometimes some chapter of Guy Steele's book ~ Common Lisp the Language - pops up. Sometimes something from Peter Seibel's Practical Common Lisp. Sometimes just some StackOverflow question and answers. Or diverse other sources. So my recommendation is: Google `Common Lisp <your function>`.

Or to search for defined functions and symbols in your repl type: `(apropos '<what you search for>)`. It will suggest you function and symbols very likely todo with your word. You could also try `(describe '<function name> 'function)`. It gives you the hyperspec url for that.

Answer (score 0):

A library I wrote might help with searching & seeing functions hierarchically while using REPL: https://github.com/albuspiroglu/cl-lib-helper

Please check the video recording in Usage section for an example.

To install, use (ql:quickload "lib-helper")